# redirect without reloading the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-router

I am doing a login page, I want that when the person is correctly logged in to redirect him to a page but without reloading, and I tried to do it with the useHistory but it does not work for me

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
import './main.css';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Link, Redirect,
  useHistory,
  useLocation, browserHistory, withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

import Register from './components/ComponentRegister'
import Login from './components/ContainerLogin'
import ChatPrincipal from './Chat/ChatPrincipal'
```

event code

```
  login = (username, password) =>{
    const history = useHistory()
    fetch('/api/login', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({username: username, password: password})
    })
    .then(r => r.json())

    .then(data =>{
      console.log(data.status)
      if(data.status === 200){
        console.log('si')
         this.setState({
          status: data.status,
          message: data.message,
          username: username
        })
        this.userSearch() 
        // window.location.href = "/"
        history.push('/') <===================================


      }else{
        this.setState({
          messageError: data.message,
          status: data.status
        })
        console.log('Error')
        const error = document.getElementById('Error')

      }
    }) 
 
    
  }
```

I don't know why it doesn't work for me, but if anyone knows a way to fix it or a library to redirect without updating please help me

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question? Perhaps you could further explain and provide more of your code. Redirecting to a new route will always mount the component linked to that route.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

`history.replace({ pathname: '/'})`

Here is working [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-wood-1jhtw?file=/src/App.js:439-454)

Please note, that in this case you need to handle changing content after replacing url